# How to use mapping inheritance and unflattening of the members?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, automapper

I have the following classes:

```
public class Address
{
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }
    //further address properties
    public string BillingStreet { get; set; }
    public string BillingZipCode { get; set; }
    //further billing address properties
    public string ShippingStreet { get; set; }
    public string ShippingZipCode { get; set; }
    //further shipping address properties
}
```

And:

```
public class Customer : Address
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The `Address` class is flattened as shown above because it is used to import records from a `CSV` file. I have many more classes just like `Customer` and I know I can use 'ForMember' to map individual members but doing so will make the mapping configuration too long and messy.

The destination classes are:

```
public class Address
{
    public ParentType ParentType { get; set}
    public AddressType AddressType { get; set}
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }
    //further address properties
} 

public class Customer
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }
    public Address BillingAddress { get; set; }
    public Address ShippingAddress { get; set; }
}
```

`ParentType` is an enum with values such as Customer, Supplier, etc. `AddressType` is also an enum with values Standard, Billing, Shipping.

Is it possible to configure `AutoMapper` in such a way to map the above successfully?

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Reverse-Mapping-and-Unflattening.html

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use the `.ForMember()` Extention method as per below:

```
public class MyProfiles : Profile
{
    public MyProfiles()
    {
        CreateMap<Customer, CustomerDto>()
            .ForMember(x => x.BillingStreet, y => y.MapFrom(c => c.BillingAddress.Street))
            .ForMember(x => x.BillingZipCode, y => y.MapFrom(c => c.BillingAddress.ZipCode))
            .ForMember(x => x.ShippingStreet, y => y.MapFrom(c => c.ShippingAddress.Street))
            .ForMember(x => x.ShippingZipCode, y => y.MapFrom(c => c.ShippingAddress.ZipCode));

    }
}
```

Comment: I known I can use `ForMember` but I'd rather avoid it because it will get quite long. So I was wondering if mapping inheritance and/or custom type converters would simplify the mapping configuration.

Comment: @Ivan-MarkDebono I see.  then I follow the question too.  Now, this is my question too